# Can't connect o Firebase console

Tags: console

I work as a designer and I sometimes need to change somethings on firebase to see how they would look like on an app. three days ago, I just couldn't log in to the firebase console. I sign in the homepage of firebase fine, but when I click "go to console" I get stuck on that animation with the logo. It keeps buffering forver. this is very confusing because it works on the MAC at work, used to work on my phone but now doesn't, and tonight I discovered that it works on my tablet but it still won't connect on my windows PC or my android phone. I did try some basic troubleshooting steps like using a different browser, connecting in incognito mode, rebooting, changing the access point (which I don't know why I thought might help). Any idea what might be causing this?

Comment: The most common cause is some ad blocker, such as ghostery.

Comment: I deactivated my adblocker and still was having the same result. Anyway, this couldn't have been the problem because it doesn't explain why I still can't log in using another browser